# Memory issues when finding masked median of masked ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I am trying to align 60 images by creating a cube (with larger dimensions than the images; 60x3000x4000) that stores information about each image and how much it is shifted by. I then combine that by finding the masking the cube for any 0 values and then find the masked median projected along the 0 axis.

However, for some reason it took ages to find the masked median (~30-40 mins), regardless if I was doing it for 2 images or 30 images. And when I ran it for 60 images, it would just say that I have run out of Application Memory. I have tried running this on both Mac OSx and Debian systems with the same issue.

Not sure how to fix this.

The relevant section of my code

```
#for loop beginning:
#    more code
     cube[k, 200-yShift[k]:200-yShift[k]+data.shape[0], 200-xShift[k]:200-xShift[k]+data.shape[1]] = data
#for loop ending:

masked_cube = ma.MaskedArray(cube, mask=cube==0)
del cube
median_mask = ma.median(masked_cube, axis = 0).filled(0)
hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(median_mask)
hdulist = fits.HDUList([hdu])
hdulist.writeto(output_file)
```

Comment: When does it hit the memory error?

Comment: about 5-10 minutes after it begins `median_mask = ma.median(masked_cube, axis = 0).filled(0)`

Comment: `median` is a complicated function, including sorting `masked_cube.sort(axis=0)`.  And it makes a (3000x4000) `meshgrid`.  `median` is a messy statistic, especially when performed on large data sets.  Much messier, say than, mean.

Comment: Be aware that `del` only removes the name from the name space, it does not trigger the garbage collector. If you want the memory to be released, place the relevant code inside a function and return only what you need. Guessing that your memory usage is already quite large, and when you reach that point, creating a third large array puts you over the limit.

Comment: Maybe the [`bottleneck`](https://github.com/kwgoodman/bottleneck) library can help you out.